# Определите, сколько заплатили за самый дешевый импортный товар

Tags: sql, база-данных, access

```
SELECT Товары.Страна,  Товары.Цена
FROM Товары
WHERE (((Товары.Страна)<>'Россия'))
AND (((Товары.Цена)=(SELECT Min(Товары.Цена) FROM Клиенты;)));
```

Это мой код. судя по задания нужна одна страна с НАИМЕНЬШЕЙ ценой. а у меня вывод 4 строки. как сделать этот самый САМЫЙ дешевый?

Comment: В таблице `Клиенты` какие поля?

Comment: ой, опечатка, спасибо, что указали) теперь все работает